# Create a PHP array with the same key for multiple values

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, wordpress

I'm posting a question already made here before and was not properly cleared for me.

I am trying to adapt a simple jquery code called “flexible calendar” and fill events trough our admin with meta keys.

The key is a date, the value a string. Here comes the problem. In order to use a jQuery calendar, I can dynamically create a JSON object like this:

```
var codropsEvents = {
'11-23-2016' : 'text',
'11-23-2016' : 'text two',
'11-20-2016' : 'some other text',
'11-19-2016' : 'Anything that is text'
};
```

But I need to get a JSON object as follows :

```
var codropsEvents = {
'11-23-2016' : 'text', 'text two',
'11-20-2016' : 'some other text',
'11-19-2016' : 'Anything that is text'
};
```

In this case, I need a code that causes them to recognize same date entries, and the nest correspontes values to the events of the same day, on the same row.

The thing is, PHP doesn't allow to use the same key in multiple rows : if I have multiple posts with the same date (a wp meta value), PHP only stores one in the array.

My calendar displays only one post per day.

How can I organize my PHP array in order to get the good format of the JSON object?

In fact, I don't need multiple rows with the same key. For every post with the same date, I need to create a row with a unique key (the date) and a unique value which will be a string containing all the posts titles.

Comment: That's not possible, neither javascript nor PHP will let you have duplicate keys in an object.

Comment: and that will also not accept duplicate keys

Comment: What you want is probably `'11-23-2015' : ['text', 'text two']`

Comment: and what js plugin is this anyway, just check the API, most likely there's a nesting way of having multiple events in the same day

Comment: that data structure seems highly unlikely to be correct ... or you need to find a more adaptable calendar

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this;

**JSON**

```
var codropsEvents = {
"11-23-2015":[
   "text",
   "some text",
   "more text",
   "bla bla"]
}
```

**PHP**

```
$codropsEvents  = array('11-23-2015'=> array('text','some text','more text','bla bla'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript object is not a valid object.

```
for (var properties in your_obj) {
   // will not return dups
}
```

---

If they are different entries and you want to treat them as such, AND you have access to the JSON creation, make it like this:

```
[
  {
    "date" : "11-23-2015",
    "content" : "text here"
  },
  {
    "date" : "11-23-2015",
    "content" : "text 2 here"
  },
  {
    "date" : "11-23-2015",
    "content" : "text 3 here"
  }
]
```

then in you php use:

```
json_decode($jsonstring);
json_decode($string, true); // for nested array
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

there was a very similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12561521/4792497

Comment: I believe the path is there. But still could not make it work. I updated my question with more details. I hope I have expressed myself better this time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused as what you want. Do you want to format calendar entries in json in js? Or, pull data from an endpoint and format it in json in PHP?

I will need more info and maybe the code to help you.