# Object issue in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var node = {
node: {
  name: "someone1",
  city: "somewhere1",
  state: "someplace1"
},
node : {
  name: "someone2",
  city: "somewhere2",
  state: "someplace2"
},
node : {
  name: "someone3",
  city: "somewhere3",
  state: "someplace3"
}
};


console.log(JSON.stringify(node.node));
//Output is {"name":"someone3","city":"somewhere3","state":"someplace3"}
```

but I need whole data like when I enter node.name..All names should display

Comment: is your `var node = ` meant to be an array?

Comment: Properties with same names? Really?

Comment: Keys in JS objects must be unique. See this topic -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561482/javascript-how-to-iterate-object-with-two-the-same-keys-and-get-two-values

Answer (score 3):

You should not keep object having properties with same name, keys within an object should be kept unique. You can have an array and loop over it

```js
var node = [
     {
      name: "someone1",
      city: "somewhere1",
      state: "someplace1"
    },{
      name: "someone2",
      city: "somewhere2",
      state: "someplace2"
    }, {
      name: "someone3",
      city: "somewhere3",
      state: "someplace3"
    }
    ]
    
node.forEach(function(item){
   console.log(item.name);
})
```

Update: setting value to input considering you nested object as pointed out in comments.

You need recursion to find all the names in the nested object

```js
$(function(){
var node = {
  "id": "429428",
  "name": "something",
  "state": {
    "filter": "98887"
  },
  "node": {
    "id": "49888",
    "name": "something2",
    "state": {
      "filter": "48765"
    },
    "node": {
      "id": "428866",
      "name": "something3",
      "state": {
         "filter": "998898"
      }
    }
  }
}
var arr = [];
function getValues(node, arr) {
    for (prop in node) {
        console.log(prop);
        if(prop == "name") {
            arr.push(node[prop]);
            
        }
        if(prop == "node") {
            getValues(node[prop], arr)
        }
    }
}

getValues(node, arr)




console.log(arr.join(" "));

document.getElementById('ip').value = arr.join(" ");
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ip"/>
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how to append the result to a variable and add as a value to input.. I

Comment: By append do you mean to join the names and then set as a value

Comment: the data from backend comes like 
{"id":"429428","name":"something","state":{"filter":"98887"},"node":{"id":"49888","name":"something2","state":{"filter":"48765"},"node":{"id":"428866","name":"something3","state":{"filter":"998898"}}}}

Comment: Now I would like to access node.name from all and append to input like you did in previous snippet

Comment: Updated the answer, please check

Comment: Shubam, Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it is not working in my context of code. I would like to append more values to the input. I am trying like.. $("#name").val(some.some + " - " + arr.join("")); --> Here both the values are not getting appended. If I try $("#name").val(some.some + " - " + node.name); I get only the last value of node.name but not all the values. Thanks again. Please Advise.

Answer (score 1):

```
var node = [
    {
        name: "someone1",
        city: "somewhere1",
        state: "someplace1"
    }, {
        name: "someone2",
        city: "somewhere2",
        state: "someplace2"
    }, {
        name: "someone3",
        city: "somewhere3",
        state: "someplace3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your node var like this:

```
var node= { node: [{ name: "someone1", city: "somewhere1", state: "someplace1" }, { name: "someone2", city: "somewhere2", state: "someplace2" }, { name: "someone3", city: "somewhere3", state: "someplace3" }]};
```

Then you can print it with:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(node));
```

It will output:

> {"node":[{"name":"someone1","city":"somewhere1","state":"someplace1"},{"name":"someone2","city":"somewhere2","state":"someplace2"},{"name":"someone3","city":"somewhere3","state":"someplace3"}]}

Answer (score 0):

You should change your data-structure.

**Variant 1: array**

```js
var node = [
 {
   name: "someone1",
   city: "somewhere1",
   state: "someplace1"
 },
 {
   name: "someone2",
   city: "somewhere2",
   state: "someplace2"
 },
 {
   name: "someone3",
   city: "somewhere3",
   state: "someplace3"
 }
];


console.log(JSON.stringify(node));
```

**Variant 2: object**

```js
var node = {
 node1: {
   name: "someone1",
   city: "somewhere1",
   state: "someplace1"
 },
 node2 : {
   name: "someone2",
   city: "somewhere2",
   state: "someplace2"
 },
 node3 : {
   name: "someone3",
   city: "somewhere3",
   state: "someplace3"
 }
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(node));
```

Answer (score -1):

Run snippet for answer and example!

```js
var nodeObject = {
  innernode1: {
      name: "someone1",
      city: "somewhere1",
      state: "someplace1"
  },
  innernode2: {
      name: "someone2",
      city: "somewhere2",
      state: "someplace2"
  },
  innernode3: {
      name: "someone3",
      city: "somewhere3",
      state: "someplace3"
  }
};

var nodeArray = [{
      name: "Bob",
      city: "Milwaukee",
      state: "Narnia"
  },
  {
      name: "Jim",
      city: "Boston",
      state: "Mass."
  },
  {
      name: "Joe Dohn",
      city: "The International Space Station",
      state: "Space"
  }
];

for(var i=0;i<nodeArray.length;i++){
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML+="<li>"+nodeArray[i].name+" lives in "+nodeArray[i].city+", "+nodeArray[i].state+"</li>";
}
```

```html
<p>Look at how the inner <code>node</code> within the outer <code>node</code> object is defined 3 times in your code. The last one will overwrite all the previous ones.</p>
<p>Try giving each node a different name, or making an array.</p>
<p>Here's an example of outputting all values from the array version, which I would personally recommend:</p>
<ol id="list">
</ol>
```