# Rename all keys in an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I'm trying to rename all the keys in an object to a new and different key which is **value** but all solutions I found on the internet show how to add a prefix to an existing key thus renaming it.

**I have the following implementation**

```js
const shippingOption = {
  "": "Automatic",
  "ES_CartasNacionalesDeMas20": "Correos: cartas ordinarias, 2-4 Days",
  "ES_CorreosCartasCertificadas": "Correos: cartas certificadas, 2-4 Days",
  "ES_CorreosCartasCertificadasUrgentes": "Correos: cartas certificadas urgentes, 1-2 Days",
  "ES_CorreosChronoexpres": "Correos Express / Paq 24, 1 Day",
  "ES_CorreosPaq48": "Correos: Paq Premium, 2 Days",
  "ES_CorreosPaq72": "Correos: Paq Estándar, 2-3 Days",
  "ES_EconomyDeliveryFromAbroad": "Envío económico desde el extranjero, 10-22 Days",
  "ES_EconomyShippingFromGC": "Envìo economico desde China/Hong Kong/Taiwan to worldwide, 11-35 Days",
  "ES_EconomySppedPAK": "Envìo SpeedPAK economico desde China/Hong Kong/Taiwan, 10-15 Days",
  "ES_ENTREGA_KIALA_8KG": "Entrega a un punto Kiala (hasta 8 kg), 2-4 Days",
  "ES_EntregaConInstalacion": "Entrega con instalación (ver detalles), 3-5 Days",
  "ES_EntregaEnElPortal": "Entrega en el portal (ver detalles), 3-5 Days",
  "ES_EntregaEnNacexShop": "Entrega en NACEX.shop, 1-2 Days",
  "ES_EnvioEstandarAIslasBalearesCeutaMelilla": "Envío estándar a Ceuta/Melilla, 3-7 Days",
  "ES_EnvioEstandarALasIslasCanarias": "Envío estándar a las islas Canarias, 3-7 Days"
}

let renamed = Object.entries(shippingOption).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
  return { ...acc,
    [`value[${k}]`]: v
  };
}, {})

console.log(renamed)
```

**Expected results**

```
 const shippingOption = {

"value": "Automatic",
"value": "Correos: cartas ordinarias, 2-4 Days",
 "value": "Correos: cartas certificadas, 2-4 Days",
 "value": "Correos: cartas certificadas urgentes, 1-2 Days"
}
```

I want every key in the object to be renamed to **value** How can I do this?

Comment: Could you put your expected result too? That will help us in answering

Comment: The code you shared generates a new object with keys that are `value[oldkey]` is this not what you want?

Comment: I've edited my question to show my desired result @NickVu

Comment: hmm I think it's impossible for your case because the key needs to be unique, but you're looking for some alternatives, you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12561521/9201587

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer should just use `v` instead of `k` if you want to name using the value of each property:

```
let renamed = Object.entries(shippingOption).reduce(
    (acc, [k, v]) => {
      return { ...acc, [`value[${v}]`]: v};
    },
    {},
);
```

Note that if you have 2 identical values, they will overwrite each other so that you will only end up with the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapped types and string literal to type the result of this operation:

```
type ValueKey<K extends string> = `value[${K}]`
type ConvertToValueKeys<T> = {} & { [K in keyof T & string as ValueKey<K>]: T[K] }
let renamed= Object.entries(shippingOption).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    return { ...acc, [`value[${k}]`]: v};
}, {} as ConvertToValueKeys<typeof shippingOption>)

renamed["value[ES_CartasNacionalesDeMas20]"] // ok 
renamed["value[ES_CartasNacionalesDeMas210]"] // err
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-CWy5Xq3XG+7faFTkOqWLg5JZBI1DWAEoSBOsGQVgCSrAAMp+WIVgmKauvoGC8DAkHsGAMDIDBrYVoEuiQQAFPAqgqDAWIwAA1hgACUgqRLeI5IpKixOBB9hgN+kAqChWjgKBVGQdKMDoNAeiaIgFqwahyqKLa+gMQYEBETAQqhDegY0sGFFgRBBoSLo4IOAxLHgZBCyOnB6l6DAAl5MJomGBJUkydS4rkaGlFaQaGiNG8UYgMgmkQWasFqKwcgSAAGgAdAgrlnBcw5yaOj6GvgXIqHySisN+EAoRAABCej6Eohi5JwvCmPoCq6ChC4mmaPLxUJkE5SoIL5YVKHBFJTLhdZtwUYqMVcRV-6qElKUKDoiiBN8IaGqVhhQLy-JQTAKUcclmwDQEbRNcO4oAL7kOQUAxMge4AGp6Ow+gVvoMQADwbu8Sx8l40BDZgAB8RAwAABoqR36AA2gAJKQFbrQAuq9227XuNGCVANYgIdujHadcTnTWz3EKQ60wAAZGQMBfRu6B4WdIAFDANaY3ArqxlBXiw-DZ2XY9gPMDWuOAzAm0GLATg6Nw07EFgWpesAUABUcQ2GKhCAoGgmA4Hg4AEQFTg+OwjSoahmjAMEX24cEiqAwRRDPRQ1BOFABywaQMABdbGta+9n2-aQuFA69jMwIq60ANzkOtwRo1T+7gJD0M0ydZ0QOdO17UTcDRtL2C4Noj0EVtXO8DzPhfXQH1w999wbOoPHgBlxhmJYViA3QrMgmCIC4TA5BpxnWc58dX35-UjnaCXJjmBAFinBXVcwDXZqOOQ0oQCABgBboIAYKhTfTgRQA)